# Can I detect MATLAB termination other than by way of a mex file mexAtExit handler?

Tags: matlab, mex

**tl;dr**

Is there any way in a Matlab .m file to detect that Matlab termination is under way?

---

I have an unmanaged library that provides an interface to my product. I have wrapped that for Matlab using a mex file. So my unmanaged library exists as a Windows DLL. I have a mex file that wraps that. In turn I have a collection of Matlab classes, implemented in various .m files that wrap the mex file. So far so good, all of this works splendidly.

I recently became aware of a problem during Matlab shutdown. Some of the Matlab classes wrap unmanaged objects. These unmanaged objects need to be destroyed when they are no longer needed. So I implement `delete` functions for the Matlab classes that wrap the unmanaged objects, and call into the mex file to destroy the objects. Obviously the mex file simply forwards these destruction calls to the unmanaged library. Again, this all works just fine.

The problem arises when Matlab shuts down and the user's workspace contains Matlab objects wrapping the unmanaged objects. Unfortunately, Matlab unloads the mex file, and then destroys the objects in the workspace. What happens next is that the `delete` function executes which calls into the mex file. Which reloads the mex file that was just unloaded. And now the attempt to destroy the unmanaged object leads to runtime errors, because my library has to be re-loaded.

Since is going to unload the mex file before destroying workspace objects, I have no choice but to skip the deletion of the unmanaged objects in that scenario. It isn't a memory leak or indeed a problem in any way, since the process is terminating. However, I do need to detect that the process is terminating. Which leads to the question, how to do that.

I'm aware of the `finish.m` termination file, but I'm not in control of that since I am providing a library. The user controls their termination file, and so I've ruled out that option. I don't even know whether or not it runs at a suitable time, i.e. before the workspace objects are destroyed.

I've built a functioning solution using `mexAtExit`. In the mex file initialization I call `mexAtExit` like so:

```
mexAtExit(atExit);
```

The `atExit` function is:

```
void atExit(void)
{
    mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 0, NULL, "mylib.atExit");
}
```

And `ofx.atExit` is in the Matlab code and is implemented like this:

```
methods(Static)

  function atExit
    mylib.mexHasUnloaded(true);
  end

  function result = mexHasUnloaded(varargin)
    global mexHasUnloadedGlobalVar;
    if isempty(mexHasUnloadedGlobalVar)
      mexHasUnloadedGlobalVar = false;
    end
    if nargin > 0
      mexHasUnloadedGlobalVar = varargin{1};
    end
    result = mexHasUnloadedGlobalVar;
  end

  ....

end
```

The `delete` function then checks `mexHasUnloaded` like this:

```
function delete(self)
  if ~mylib.mexHasUnloaded
    mylibMex(mylib.mexDestroyObject, self.handle);
  end
end
```

Whilst this appears to work, I'm not at all happy with it.

- Can I really only detect Matlab termination from inside a mex file? I would like to detect this directly in the .m file and it feels like that ought to be possible. Is it possible?
- Do I really need to use a global variable like that? Can't I find a better way to look after this state? I tried using a `persistent` variable but that was just as hacky and did not work. The `persistent` variable was re-initialised at some point during the termination which meant that `mexHasUnloaded` started returning `false` after it had earlier been set to `true`.
- Or is there a different solution to my problem? Can I force my mex file to stay loaded until after the workspace objects are deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work to `mexLock()` your MEX file so that it doesn't get unloaded, so the `delete` methods can do the right thing at shutdown?

Comment: OK, my first trial seems to show that this has the desired effect. I'm quite happy to keep the mex file loaded permanently.  I'll do a bit more testing.  Thank you very much.

Comment: This does indeed solve my problem, albeit in a manner different from how I originally envisaged. I updated the question a little so that I could accept your answer. Thank you. Would you be able to confirm that shutdown detection is not possible from an m file?

Comment: The only documented `.m` file method of detecting shutdown that I'm aware of is `finish.m` - which, as you observe, is not suitable for library authors.